# Decoding problem with files and serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

In my API using Django Rest Framework I have a function based view for part of a sign up process for using Stripe. The view succefully sends everything to stripe and updates my sites database with the proper information, but when trying to return the serializer data I get this error:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Assuming it has to do with the files needed for personal identification

Here is the view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def StripePersonalOnboard(request):
    serializer = StripePersonalSerializer(data=request.data)
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        phone_number = serializer.validated_data.get('phone_number')
        ss_number = serializer.validated_data.get('ss_number')
        id_front = serializer.validated_data.get('id_front')
        id_back = serializer.validated_data.get('id_back')

        try:
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_TEST_SEC_KEY

            id_front_file = stripe.File.create(
                purpose='identity_document',
                file=id_front
            )
            id_back_file = stripe.File.create(
                purpose='identity_document',
                file=id_back
            )

            stripe.Account.modify(
                profile.stripe_acc_id,
                individual= {
                        'phone': phone_number,
                        'id_number': ss_number,
                        'verification': {
                            'document': {
                                'back': id_back_file,
                                'front': id_front_file
                        }
                    }
                }
            )

            profile.stripe_id_front_tkn = id_front_file.id
            profile.stripe_id_back_tkn = id_back_file.id
            profile.save(update_fields=['stripe_id_front_tkn', 'stripe_id_back_tkn'])
            return Response(serializer.validated_data)
        
        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
                #invalid parameters were provided
                return Response(e.error.message)
            
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: What line is causing this error?  What's the stack trace show?

Comment: @floatingLomas yes, it's when I try to return the validated data from the serializer

Comment: Not sure what to suggest, as I don't really have enough info to help here.